# How can I make my page resize when screen height changes only

Tags: css, media-queries, height, screen, responsive

I have a question about responsive pages. I have a page for my website which looks fine on an apple macbook air. However, when I looked at my website from my mothers laptop, the screen cut the homepage partway off, because her screen is smaller. I have responsive images and used media queries for small screens, but I can't seem to make my page look good when it's on a smaller screen. The images do resize when I change the width of the screen, just not if I only change the height. Why not? I tried to fix this by doing a media query for only small heights, but that doesn't work either. How can I make sure my page also looks good on smaller heights?

If you need code I can post it or send a github link, one or the other. :)

Comment: can u share a working snippet or codepen or, any similar so that we can see the issue you are facing, or use `@media (min-height: 600px) { }` or `@media (max-height: 800px) { }` and see if it works

Comment: yeah the media query thing didn't work. My github link is https://github.com/ellistolsma/portfolio2.git if you're ok with working with github? The issue is with all the pages but i'm now working on just index.html. It's probably an issue with the responsiveness because i'm just starting out with code and don't always know what i'm doing lol. Learning from mistakes I guess, but this is just frustrating :P hope you can help!

Comment: i see only one file `.gitattributes`, can u push all your changes

Comment: sorry wrong link! here I hope this one works https://github.com/ellistolsma/ellistolsma2.git :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the height of the div by jquery and set the height to css. You can follow the below code and customize at your own way.

```
 $(window).on("scroll",function(e){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();    
    if (scroll > 100 ) {
         var height = $('.height-of-the-div-you-want').innerHeight();
         // alert(height);
         $('.set-this-height-dynmicallty').css('height', height);
     }
});
```

Comment: Hm I could try this but the issue is just with the whole page. Nothing in the page resizes vertically. I dont really want to overwork it with having to resize every part with javascript code.